# How would I align imagebuttons along this semicircle path in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I want to add an imagebutton along this path that I have created in android studio. I have been trying to find a tutorial that would help me with pragmatically placing a few buttons along this path I have made.

I haven't tried anything but researching tutorials to find out what to do because I am completely lost. I just need someone who has done this or can refer me to something to learn.

```
public class MyView extends View {

Paint paint;
Path path;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    final RectF oval = new RectF();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);


   ;

    oval.set(0, 20, 500, 1000);
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, 180, false, paint);


}

}
```

I expect to learn how to align a few buttons along this path.